# Dynamically loading module and component in angular giving error in production mode

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10

I am trying to create an angular module and component on the fly and try to compile it and render it.

Its working fine during development but as soon as i am running ng build --prod it started giving error and my code stopped working.

below is the sample code that i am using compile my only module and component.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { Compiler, Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Injector, Input, NgModule, NgModuleFactory, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { LoadAppComponentModule } from '../load-app-component/load-app-component.module';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-load-widgets-to-app',
      templateUrl: './load-widgets-to-app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./load-widgets-to-app.component.css']
    })
    export class LoadWidgetsToAppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private compiler: Compiler,
       private injector: Injector) { }
 ngOnInit(): void {

 }
 private async addComponent(temp, properties, css, from) {
    const TemplateComponent = Component({ "template": temp, "styles": [css] })(class { })

    const tmpModule = await NgModule({ declarations: [TemplateComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule, LoadAppComponentModule], schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] })(class {
    });
    const moduleFactory = tmpModule instanceof NgModuleFactory ? tmpModule
      : (await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(tmpModule));

    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
    const componentFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TemplateComponent);
   // this.container.clear();
    const component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
       Object.assign(component.instance, properties);
    if (this._appComponent && from === 'app') {
      component.instance['itemData'] = this._appComponent;
    } else if (this._section && from === 'section') {
      component.instance['section'] = this._section;
    }
  }


    });
```

The error i am getting after build please find below:

```
ERROR Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
    at $ (main.js:1)
    at Function.get (main.js:1)
    at Je (main.js:1)
    at new Gm (main.js:1)
    at rb (main.js:1)
    at e.hb [as compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync] (main.js:1)
    at e.addComponent (79.js:1)
    at 79.js:1
    at l.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1)
ns @ main.js:1
```

Comment: generally if you ask this question, you are doing something terribly wrong, and this logic should be refactored somehow. I believe you won't get answer, as it is pretty complex to make it work. if you load the compiler, and solve all the problem that can be gracefully solved - you meet the problem that metadata of dependant modules is lost (erased on compile phase). this problem requires adjusting the compilation settings which will result in app performance loss.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, Do you have any idea if i can add a selector const abc ='<section-widget [data]="_dsData"></section-widget>' dynamically inside angular component and make it working ?

Comment: if the `selection-widget` component is part of a statically compiled module than it is the hard problem. Metadata of dependant module is lost